# Rails: compile migrations into one file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration

We've been developing an application for a year and there are some errors in the migrations. Is there a way to compile them into one file so that we can eliminate any errors and the like without sorting through hundreds of individual files? Or can we reset the migrations so the version running right now is the first for new installations?

Comment: What kind of errors? How did you fix those errors? Or better yet, how did you end up with the valid schema you have now?

Comment: i think you can just write a new migration where you just fix all the previous errors...like adding a default value, removing unnecessary columns etc.....

Comment: Most of them stem from having a migration half-finish, and having to comment out parts that passed and the like. So while for the current installation it works fine, but for new ones it'll fail.

Comment: Migrations are intended to be temporary, don't be afraid to throw them all out and just use `schema.rb`/`structure.sql`, seeds, etc. In fact, I would strongly recommend that you delete your migrations as soon as you don't need them anymore.

Comment: So I can safely run `db:schema:load` for new installations and trash my migrations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Migrations are already "compile" into one file call `schema.rb` located into the `db` folder of your rails application.

You can load the schema from the following rake task:

```
rake db:schema:load
```